# Should links to partner sites use rel=nofollow

Tags: nofollow

I use pretty links to shorten/protect outbound referral links to commission programs off of a review page (for example). I'm wondering if I should make links to partner sites no-follow?

My site is recommending the end site that I am trying to send customers to, but it's unclear how I should handle the links.

Comment: What exactly is a "partner site"?   Do you have a business relationship with them?  Do you get a benefit from referring customers to them?

Comment: A "partner site" is a site I work with as an affiliate marketer to drive new customers to. I am paid a commission by the partner site for this traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting paid by the site for customers then Google requires that you use `rel=nofollow` on those links.  Google's help document on the subject is [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) and it says:

> **Paid links**: A site's ranking in Google search results is partly based on analysis of those sites that link to it. In order to prevent paid links from influencing search results and negatively impacting users, we urge webmasters use nofollow on such links. Search engine guidelines require machine-readable disclosure of paid links in the same way that consumers online and offline appreciate disclosure of paid relationships (for example, a full-page newspaper ad may be headed by the word "Advertisement"). [More information on Google's stance on paid links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en).